# Nodejs with express : Why my middleware is executing twice Here is the code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

This is my code here..!

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

let myFunc = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('This is middleware');
    next();
}

app.use(myFunc);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('This is get /');
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running at port 3000....');
});
```

In this I have created a middleware called myFunc but the output is not as I thought it would be

```
Server is running at port 3000....
This is middleware
This is get /
This is middleware
```

Comment: Add `console.log(req.url)` to the middleware. I bet the browser is asking for favicon.

Comment: I think the other request is for favicon

Comment: the other one is for favicon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

app.use is running every time you trigger app. in this case you trigger twice. app.get and app.listen

Comment: Hmmmmm, are you sure about that? Neither declaring a route nor starting a server should run middleware or somehow rerun `app.use`.

Comment: No its not working I tried to remove the app.get but then too its executing twice!

Comment: No I started the server and reloaded the page I got error on the webpage which is completely acceptable but then too its executing twice!

Comment: @AdityaPradhan This answer makes no sense. I am sure the browser is sending anothre request asking for a favicon. You could easily check this by making request using curl `curl http://localhost:3000`. The middleware will only run once.

Comment: this is not an opinion, it is from the docs: middleware mounted without a path will be executed for every request to the app

Comment: Yes  for every **request** Neither `app.get` nor `app.listen` makes a request.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Yes I think your right when i requested using Postman it worked and the middleware executed only once

Comment: neither `app.get` nor `app.listen` call his function. Instead every request that comes from the browser does call his function.

Answer (score 17):

This happens because the browser is requesting two files. The first will be for `/` and the second is likely for `favicon.ico`. If you want to see *why* this is being called change your one function to look like this:

```
let myFunc = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('This is middleware', req.originalUrl);
  next();
}
```

Then it will output the URL that was requested for each time the browser hits the server.

Comment: You're absolutely right. This is because of favicon.ico file. Browser sends request twice: 1 for "/" and 1 for "/favicon.ico"... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your browser automatically sends a request to `/favicon.ico` URL. `console.log(req.url)` will show you what's happening.

```js
let myFunc = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('This middleware was triggered for the URL:' + req.url);
    next();
}
```

Try sending requests to the server using postman as it does not send anything automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Your static files also share the same url as the one u are trying to use.
So most likely you will have something like this:
localhost:3000/:variable

Here this url will match a lot of stuff

Answer (score -2):

> As @DavidWhite said app.use is running every time you trigger app. in this
>   case you trigger twice. app.get and app.listen
>    You should use the middleware this way

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

let myFunc = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('This is middleware');
    next();
}

app.get('/', myFunc,(req, res) => {
    console.log('This is get /');
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running at port 3000....');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

When you use `app.use(myFunc);` you apply middleware to all app. 
And you are using app.get and app.listen, that's why the middleware triggered twice. Try to use middlewere in get query

Comment: I tried to remove app.get and but still its executing twice!

Comment: Yes, it is normal, because you use a middleware function with no mount path. This code is executed for every request to the router. No understand why it is called twice please add console.log(req.url) in middleware  as @Yuri mentioned.

Comment: neither `app.get` nor `app.listen` call his function. Instead every request that comes from the browser does call his function.